# JSON and webservice in Android Listview

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I'm try to get the data from server using web service I have a web service.
The webservice returns data in JSON format. 
this is my web service

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetTituli() As String
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.123\cmdsql;uid=user;pwd=password;database=testjoson")
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select Id_Agjenda,Titulli,Useri,data_takimit,Kategoria,data_e_publikimit,e_kryer,rezultati from tblagjenda ;", conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds)
    conn.Close()
    Dim TitulliArray()() As String = New String(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)() {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each rs As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        TitulliArray(i) = New String() {rs("Titulli").ToString()}
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim sJSON As String = js.Serialize(TitulliArray)
    Return sJSON
End Function
```

this is my json

```
[["test from json"],["test from json2"],["test from jso3"],["test from json4"]]
```

this is my activity

```
enter code here
public class Notat_e_studentit extends Fragment {
SessionManager session;
private static final String Soap_Action_JSONEXP="http://tempuri.org/GetTituli";
private static final String METHOD_NAME_JSONEXP="GetTituli";
private static final String NAMESPACEEXP="http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL_jsEXP="http://mydomain/webservice/Service1.asmx?wsdl";
private String TAG="beni";
ListView listnewlend;
private static String responseJSON;
ProgressBar pg;
Gson gson=new Gson();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    session=new SessionManager(getActivity());
    session.checkLogin();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.notat_e_studentit,container,false);
    return view;    
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listnewlend=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cmdlista);
    Thread cmdthredlista=new Thread(){
        @Override
    public void run(){
            SoapObject cmdrequest=new SoapObject(NAMESPACEEXP,METHOD_NAME_JSONEXP);
            System.out.println("requsest "+cmdrequest);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(cmdrequest);
            HttpTransportSE ahttptransport=new HttpTransportSE(URL_jsEXP);
            try {
                System.out.println("request "+cmdrequest);
                ahttptransport.call(Soap_Action_JSONEXP,envelope);
                //final SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                responseJSON=response.toString();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String[] placelist;              
                            placelist=gson.fromJson(responseJSON,String[].class);
                            ArrayAdapter<String>cmdlistaadapteri;
                            cmdlistaadapteri=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,placelist);
                            listnewlend.setAdapter(cmdlistaadapteri);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("error ");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error ");
            }
        }
    };
    cmdthredlista.start();
}}
```

but the data will not dispaly in the listview.
this is my logcat

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3
```

11-20 14:41:07.186      903-903/com.cmd.dfa W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
[
 ["a"],
 ["b"],
 ["c"]
]
```

It's a List of List...

You should have

```
[
 "a",
 "b",
 "c"
]
```

which is a list of (object) String.

You json should be

```
["test from json", "test from json2" , "test from jso3" , "test from json4"]
```

If you **can't** change your json, you may want to try with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> placelist;              
placelist = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>()
{
}.getType());
```

And retrieve a string with

```
placelist.get(index).get(0); // 0
```

but it's .......bad ;-)